# Steps to get the list of pdf files from FTP in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ftp

I'm new to IOS Development. This is the first time i'm hearing about FTP in IOS .I'm not getting, How to proceed further . I got this code https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html .
But i didn't understand from this code . 
I need to list the pdf files and folders from FTP . First i don't know how to establish the connection to FTP . Can any one please help me with steps.

Answer (score 0):

I fyou look in ListController.m, listOrCancelAction is called when you click on List button.
In turn if you put a break point in startReceive you would see that
CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL is opening a "Open a CFFTPStream for the URL" with a specified URL.
I suggest you put a couple more break points and step through the code?
NSStreamDelegate is being used as callbacks when something is happening in particular

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
```

is called when connection is open or data is received. 
Hope this is enough to get you started.

```
entryToAdd = [self entryByReencodingNameInEntry:(__bridge NSDictionary *) thisEntry encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

in parseListData will have file name in kCFFTPResourceName which of course you can parse to find out if it is a PDF file. You may look at kCFFTPResourceType to see if you can use to determine file type, not sure.